# React server not starting - something with renderProps

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I have a React app and here is my server code:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  let history = createMemoryHistory();
  let store = configureStore();
  let routes = createRoutes(history);
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(301, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    } else if (renderProps == null) {
      res.status(404).send('Not found');
    } else {
      let { query, params } = renderProps;
      let comp = renderProps.components[renderProps.components.length - 1];
      console.log('fetching');
      comp.fetchData({ store, params })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('done fetching');
          let html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
              <Provider store={store}>
              { <RouterContext {...renderProps}/> }
            </Provider>
          );
          const template = store.getState().template;
          const og = templateToOpenGraph(template);
          const full = wrap(html, store.getState(), og);
          res.set({ 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=300' })
          res.send(full);
        })
    }
  });
})
```

When I start the server, it starts up just fine. But when I hit a route (any route), I get an error:

`TypeError: comp.fetchData is not a function`

What do I need to do? I'm not the greatest with react, so if I'm missing something obvious, please do let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a react problem if the error is occurring server side.
What library is being used here? "let comp = renderProps.components[renderProps.components.length - 1];"
reading the documentation for that library should answer your question.

Comment: @Dave Lots of people use react on the server side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be method `fetchData` in your component.

I don't have your routes config but for example you have something like this in your `routes.js` file

`<Route path="/" component={Root}>
  <Route path="view/:id" component={View} />
  ...
 </Route>`

When you load page `http://example.com/view/1231` in your browser, component `View` will be rendered. You should implement method `fetchData`. This method will be called before rendering `View`

```
class View extends React.Component {
  fetchData() {
    // implement fetch data here
  }
  ...
}
```